# Import upsell products for another product in magento from CSV

Tags: magento, csv, import, product

Is it possible to import Upsell products from a CSV in magento ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can import Upsell products via the CSV using the column "_links_upsell_sku".  Put the SKU of the upsell product in this column, and for multiple products put their SKU's in subsequent rows. Make sure additional rows have a blank "sku" column.

- For Upsell products use: "_links_upsell_sku"
- For Related products use: "_links_related_sku"
- For Cross sell products use: "_links_crosssell_sku"

Make sure the SKU's exist or you may get import errors.

I verified this works on Magento 1.6.2.

Comment: I can confirm this works on Magento 1.9.0.1.  I can't believe I couldn't find this information anywhere else.  Thank you!  Also, fyi, I could only get this to work using the basic import (System -> Import/Export -> Import), but I couldn't figure out how to do it with the dataflow profiles.

Answer (score 0):

This is brilliant and simple.  All I could find in search engines to accomplish this were commercial plugins.  This definitely does the trick, so hopefully we can bolster the SEO on this thread a bit.  If you're looking to import related products to Magento, this is it.

Answer (score -1):

Or you could use this! I have not tired it but has good reviews.

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=What_is_magmi